# Ubuntu - One process running - Tons of memory used

Tags: wubi, performance, ram, memory-usage

I've installed Ubuntu using the Microsoft Windows Installer, and it's running pretty slow.
I've got 3.8 GB ram on my computer, and by running `free -m` I'm getting the following results :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3920       3440        479          0       1174       1457
-/+ buffers/cache:        809       3110
Swap:          255          0        255
```

Only 479 out of 3440 MB is free, while to only process running at the moment if Firefox.
I've changed the swappiness to 10, but still no change is seen.
I'd like to know  why so much memory is used and how could I fix it and possibly make my computer run faster.
Any solution would be grateful , thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The fact is WUBI has memory leak bug as reported here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/576751 . So thats obvious.

Unused RAM is wasted RAM.

Linux uses RAM very different then Windows. According to your output of free -m the majority of my RAM was tied up in caching data.So

Flush file system buffers for safety

```
sync
```

Become root

```
sudo bash
```

And for clearing cache mem use -

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

for watching running proccess use-

```
top
```

Dont worry mine output is similar to yours.